# How to iterate through multidimensional list/dict in a template

Tags: python, django, templates, iteration

I try to rebuild this example:
https://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/

I have a model "Product" and a model "Order". Order has a foreignkey to "product". So for 1 Product I have N Orders

In my template I have to display a lot of information so I would like to avoid to do "for order in Product.order_set.all()" in my template

In my template, if I write :

```
{{ object_list.1.related_items }}
```

everything is fine and I get what I want
but if I write:

```
{% for i in object_list %}
    {{ object_list.i.related_items }}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't get a result.

Can somebody tell me how I solve this problem?

My object_list is nearly the same as in the above example:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
i = 0
qs = Product.objects.all()
obj_dict = dict([(obj.id, obj) for obj in qs])
objects = Order.objects.filter(producttyp__in=qs)
relation_dict = {}
for obj in objects:
   relation_dict.setdefault(obj.producttyp_id, []).append(obj)
for id, related_items in relation_dict.items():
    obj_dict[id].related_items = related_items
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    context = {'object_list':self.obj_dict}
    return render(request,self.template_name,context)
```

the only change i did is from 
obj_dict[id]._related_items to obj_dict[id].related_items because of the not allowed underscore?!

How do I print the list in my template like:

```
- Product A
    - Order 1
    - Order 2
    - Order 5
- Product B
    - Order 3
    - Order 6
```

best regards

Comment: So your `obj.producttyp` refers to a `Product`? Can you share the `Product` and `Order` model? I think you do not need to do all that magic yourself, you can simply use `.prefetch_related(..)` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is logical, since here Django interprets `i` not as the variable, but as the an identifier, so it aims to access `object_list.i`, or `object_list['i']`, not `object_list.1` for example.

You however do not need `i` here, you can just access the `related_items` of the `object`, like:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object.related_items }}
{% endfor %}
```

If `related_items` is, as the name suggests, a collection as well, we can iterate over these items as well:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% for subitem in object.related_items %}
        {{ subitem }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

for a dictionary, we can access the `.values`, like:

```
{% for object in object_dict.values %}
    {{ object.related_items }}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: as for the specific case of the listview. You can use [**`.prefetch_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all the relations with one extra query:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('order_set')
    template = 'my_template.html'
```

In the template you can then render this like:

```
<ul>
    {% for product in object_list %}
        <li>{{ product }}</li>
        <ul>
        {% for order in product.order_set %}
            <li>{{ order }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but theres still no result displayed. perhaps it helps to provide more info. this is the object_list: `products = Product.objects.all()
    i = 0
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    obj_dict = dict([(obj.id, obj) for obj in qs])
    objects = Order.objects.filter(producttyp__in=qs)
    relation_dict = {}
    for obj in objects:
        relation_dict.setdefault(obj.producttyp_id, []).append(obj)
    for id, related_items in relation_dict.items():
        obj_dict[id].related_items = related_items
    print(obj_dict) context = {'object_list':self.obj_dict}`

Comment: thats what i am trying to do: https://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/

Comment: Please edit your quesion and provide a more clear explanation.

Comment: thank you! i thought this will result in multiple queries too, wherefore i made this complicated workaround, this is much easier!, just had to make some changes in your code:
                              {% for product in object_list.all %}
                                  {% for order in product.order_set.all %}

Comment: @Rune: the `.all` for `object_list` normally is *not* necessary, unless you did some extra processing.

Comment: Hello, I have still one problem left. By using .all() in my template I'm getting ALL orders, even if i past my queryset with an additional filter() in the view. If im using without all i get a "related manager, object is not iterable" error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rune: you can not filter the related model with a `.filter(..)`, If you want to filter the related model, you should use a `Prefetch` object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

Comment: thanks a lot. that did it! one question...what is ....get().choice_set.all() in the example for? I have done it without this snippet now and still works.

Comment: @Rune: that is, as far as I know, to demonstrate how it works, it thus shows that if you retrieve the object, that you get the requested queryset.